# Functions of $\mathbb{R}^d$ preserving convexity of sets

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity

Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, with $d\geq 2$, such that:

- $f$ is injective,
- For any convex set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $f(A)$ is also convex.

What can we say about $f$ ? In particular, is $f$ necessarily affine ? I tend to think yes, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 22):

See *Meyer, Walter; Kay, David C.*, [**A convexity structure admits but one real linearization of dimension greater than one**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-7.1.124), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 7, 124-130 (1973). [ZBL0271.52002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0271.52002).

> Theorem 4. If $V$ and $W$ are real vector spaces with $\dim V>1$, and $f:V\to W$ is a one-to-one mapping which preserves convexity, then $f$ is either linear (if $f(0)=0$) or is the translate of a linear map.

Comment: Having just recently explained to my students the distinction between linear and affine, I am somewhat amused that the authors chose not to use the word "affine".